# Advice on Collectionview scenario

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Need some advice on how to approach a scenario using a Collectionview. In short, the app has a CV displaying images where you can tap a cell with a thumbnail of an image and it will then display a fullscreen view of that image. I'm accomplishing this by instantiating a new UIView (not from storyboard) inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath. So the fullscreen view of the image from the cell is just a new UIView triggered from tapping the cell and I set the view's image to be the same as the cell's image...simple enough. The fullscreen view also has a button that relates to each image. Tapping the fullscreen image closes the image and goes back to the CV. All of this works perfectly.

However, I just realized that I would also like to be able to swipe through all the images while in fullscreen mode...basically very similar to how the iOS photo album works. I was able to write some code pretty quickly to do this by adding a swipe gesture to didSelectItemAtIndexPath and set the action selector to a method to handle the swipes, which worked. However, the result of this was really just changing the image for the original cell selected (tapped). So I'm not able to keep track of the selected cell while swiping through the images in fullscreen mode.

So I need advice on how to approach this. I know there has to be examples out there for something like this, but I was unable to find any. Does anyone have any advice on how I should implement this? Thanks!

Code from didSelectItemAtIndexPath...

```
self.fullScreenImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width-10, self.view.bounds.size.height-15)];
self.fullScreenImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightSwipe:)];
[rightSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[self.fullScreenImage addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSwipe:)];
[leftSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[self.fullScreenImage addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];

if (!self.isFullScreen) {
    self.fullScreenImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
    __weak BaseViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        NSLog(@"Starting animiation!");
        weakSelf.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        weakSelf.myCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        weakSelf.fullScreenImage.center = self.view.center;
        weakSelf.fullScreenImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        weakSelf.fullScreenImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:coffeeImageData.imageURL.path];
        weakSelf.fullScreenImage.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; // zoom in effect
        [weakSelf.view addSubview:self.fullScreenImage];
        [weakSelf.fullScreenImage addSubview:likeButton]; // add the button to the view
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
            NSLog(@"Animation finished!");
            weakSelf.isFullScreen = YES;
        }
    }];
    return;
}
```

Handling the swipe gesture from...
    - (void)handleLeftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

```
// make sure indexForSwiping is not > than size of array
if (self.indexForSwiping != [self.imageLoadManager.coffeeImageDataArray count]-1) {
    self.indexForSwiping += 1;
    NSString *cacheKey = self.allCacheKeys[self.indexForSwiping];

    if (cacheKey) {
        [self.imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:cacheKey done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
            if (image) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                    self.fullScreenImage.image = image;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    NSLog(@"swiping");
                }];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This framework already have such functionality, so you can look into source code to understand how it works...

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Answer (score 0):

I would have the view be part of the viewController and not only part of your function. Then, have the viewController manage the swipe, image, and location of the image. When your collectionView is tapped, set the location in your viewController so that when a swipe is caught you can increment by one and update your view with the new image. Let me know if that wasn't clear enough and I can try clarifying

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Are you saying to have the UIView that's displaying the fullscreen image exist in the VC via storyboard? If so, I'm not sure how I would do that in this scenario. Currently, it is in the viewcontroller but instantiated programmatically inside the didSelectItem method.

Comment: Can you show the code where you instantiate it and how you are handling the swipe? I think I could clarify better if I saw exactly how you are doing that.

Comment: Thanks for your help...just edited original post to show some of the code from didSelectItemAtIndexPath and the method for handling the left swipe gesture. Right swipe is the same, just with a different index to access the data in the array.

Comment: You're doing pretty much what I meant for you to do. If the collectionView is being modified I would see if you can create a copy of the image and set that as the image your imageView is using, seems there might be a pointer issue causing it to update both places at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep looking into it.